# cant print ASCII ART (python)

Tags: python, ascii-art

I tried to use the designs of this site to write a codegame program for python, but I can't understand why the designs I make get errors.

I tried this :

```
left == '''
((`\        ___ \\ '--._
         .'`   `'    o  )
        /    \   '. __.'
       _|    /_  \ \_\_
jgs   {_\______\-'\__\_\''')
```

AND MY ERROR WAS:
"message": "String literal is unterminated",

Comment: Please also include your code and see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted

Comment: The problem is caused by the backslashes. Please see the linked duplicate. For future questions, please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to understand how to post code so that it shows up properly.

Comment: @R__i_ the code was included, OP just didn't know how to format it properly.

Comment: Change the first line to `left = r'''` and it should work.  Note only one equals, and notice the `r`.  Also remove the very last `)`.